# Store Facebook users like

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

I'm working on an application but what i want to do is get the user likes and store it in my database

But when i try to save it in the database it won't insert it in my database

```
$likes = $facebook->api('/me/likes');

$fblikes = '';

foreach($likes['data'] as $like){

    $fblikes .= $like['name'].', ';

}

$insert = "INSERT INTO users (name, email, gender, liked)
                VALUES (
                '$fbname',
                '$fbemail',
                '$fbgender',
                '$fblikes'
                )";

$add_bericht = mysql_query($insert);
```

But whenever i remove $fblikes from the insert sql it will insert into my database

Any idea's ?

Comment: How does the table ddl look? `SHOW CREATE TABLE users`

Answer (score 2):

I think there is an escaping problem in your query. You are (Very) susceptible to SQL Injection.
See this post on how to prevent it: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Fixed : $user_likes = mysql_real_escape_string($fblikes);

Thanks m8

Comment: Great. So if this answers your question would you please mark it as suck? There is a checkmark next to my answer to mark it as 'accepted'. Thanks!